# не мог долго установить библиотеку pyspectator, в итоге скачал архив и тут эта ошибка

Tags: python-3.x

```
C:\Users\Mr Robot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\Mr': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Mr Robot> & python "c:/Users/Mr Robot/Desktop/hello.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Mr Robot/Desktop/hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Robot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspectator-1.2.1-py3.8.egg\pyspectator\processor.py", line 60, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Mr Robot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspectator-1.2.1-py3.8.egg\pyspectator\processor.py", line 176, in __get_processor_temperature_reader
  File "C:\Users\Mr Robot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspectator-1.2.1-py3.8.egg\pyspectator\temperature_reader.py", line
50, in get_reader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wmi'
```

Comment: Нет модуля wmi. 
https://blog.ipswitch.com/managing-windows-system-administration-with-wmi-and-python

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке написано что он не распознаёт пробел в имени пользователя `Mr Robot` .попробуй изменить в винде на слитное `MrRobot` . Только русское не ставь, с кирилицей иногда тоже проблемы бывают.

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте, что у вас установлены инструменты сборки Microsoft Visual C++. Чаще всего проблема именно в этом. Вот ссылка на скачивание: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ru%2F
2. Если не помогло, следуйте слудующим инструкциям:

Скачанный архив с библиотекой распакуйте и измените файл "pyspectator-1.2.1\requirements\windows.txt" следующим образом:

```
psutil>=2.1.1
netifaces>=0.10.4
pyvalid>=0.9
pytest>=2.6.2
enum34>=1.0
wmi >= 1.4.9
```

Затем в терминале пропишите следующую команду: python setup.py install

*А вообще, подтяните английский и пользуйтесь также иностранными форумами.*

Comment: всё это уже сделал, после всего вылетела эта ошибка, иностранные форумы читал, похожих ошибок пока не обнаружил

Comment: наконец нашёл решение, но вылетела ошибка: wmi.x_access_denied: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217405, 'OLE error 0x80041003', None, None)>

Comment: на форуме нашёл что нужно запустить скрипт через командную строку от имени администратора, и скрипт заработал)

Comment: но я буду благодарен, если вы напишите как можно обойти последнюю ошибку без прав администратора

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код, где вы используете эту библиотеку. Теоретически можно заставить его работать без root.